# SoundTouch and JNI

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, soundtouch

I want to call  this native method from java:
`void SoundTouch::putSamples(const SAMPLETYPE *samples, uint nSamples)`

In My Java code I have this:
`public native void putSamples(byte[] samples, int nSamples);`

Now I want to write the JNI part to bridge between this method and function, but the native function expects an argument of the type `SAMPLETYPE`, but I have no idea how to 'convert' from `jbyteArray` to `SAMPLETYPE`.

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void Java_com_example_test_SoundTouch_putSamples(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jbyteArray samples ,jint numSamples){
[Some magic to convert samples to FRAMETYPE I guess...]
st.putSamples(???, numSamples); 
}
```

If using eclipse search, the only seemingly relevant piece of code I found was in STTypes.cpp, which is: `typedef float  SAMPLETYPE;`

Does that mean I have to convert my byte[] to a float[], if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Since SAMPLETYPE is really float, you should use float instead of byte.

```
public native void putSamples(float[] samples, int nSamples);
```

and...

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void Java_com_example_test_SoundTouch_putSamples(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jfloatArray samples ,jint numSamples){
    float *samplesArray = env->GetFloatArrayElements(samples, 0);
    st.putSamples((SAMPLETYPE *)samplesArray, numSamples); 
}
```

Comment: I have been facing an issue with compiling with ndk the same function, please have a look at my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783644/soundtouch-library-compile-issue