# Soundtouch library compile issue

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-audiorecord, soundtouch

I am trying to compile Soundtouch library with Android NDK.  I successfully installed Cygwin and SWIG required for Soundtouch library.  When I try to run ndk-build.cmd, i am getting an error

> jni/soundtouch/wrapper_wrap.cpp: In function 'void Java_com_talkingyeti_jni2_wrapperJNI_SoundTouch_1putSamples(JNIEnv*, _jclass*, jlong, _jobject*, jlong, jlong)':
>   jni/soundtouch/wrapper_wrap.cpp:545: error: 'SAMPLETYPE' was not declared in this scope
>   jni/soundtouch/wrapper_wrap.cpp:545: error: 'arg2' was not declared in this scope
>   jni/soundtouch/wrapper_wrap.cpp:553: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
>   jni/soundtouch/wrapper_wrap.cpp:560: error: expected ')' before 'const'
>   jni/soundtouch/wrapper_wrap.cpp:560: error: expected ')' before ';' token
>   make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/soundtouch/wrapper_wrap.o] Error 1

This issue happens with the following block of wrapper_wrap.cpp :

```
  SWIGEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_talkingyeti_jni2_wrapperJNI_SoundTouch_1putSamples(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong jarg1, jobject jarg1_, jlong jarg2, jlong jarg3) {
  soundtouch::SoundTouch *arg1 = (soundtouch::SoundTouch *) 0 ;
  SAMPLETYPE *arg2 = (SAMPLETYPE *) 0 ;
  uint arg3 ;
  uint *argp3 ;

  (void)jenv;
  (void)jcls;
  (void)jarg1_;
  arg1 = *(soundtouch::SoundTouch **)&jarg1; 
  arg2 = *(SAMPLETYPE **)&jarg2; 
  argp3 = *(uint **)&jarg3; 
  if (!argp3) {
    SWIG_JavaThrowException(jenv, SWIG_JavaNullPointerException, "Attempt to dereference null uint");
    return ;
  }
```

Please suggest me what all changes I need to make on the SAMPLETYPE to compile NDK properly and to generate SO file.

Answer (score 2):

It's seem you missed a header. Make sure you have:

```
#include "soundtouch/include/SoundTouch.h"
```

and

```
using namespace soundtouch;
```

Comment: have you integrated soundtouch library in your apps?

Comment: Yes, in an Android App which is to modify sound Tempo

Comment: @mmdc im facing this issue again, could you please share the sample code? thank you